# How to embed google form which is created using script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a form using script in google now i want to add this in my website and want to share the form. I don't know how to do that?? So if anyone knows how to do that please let me know i need it very urgently..

Answer (score -3):

Go into the Form Editor, open File menu, select "Embed...", and use the "Embed Form" dialog to generate the HTML for an iframe you can embed in your web site.

[image]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is different, we have two types of forms using Google Services:
1 - Google From came from a SpreadSheet or...
2 - Just using GS (Google Script)
Your answer is from the first case